Newly adopted cat (adopted because she was getting euthanised) hissing at me and scared
She's about one year old, and I rescued her 2.5 weeks ago. She was really scared, obviously, so I let her 'live her life'; my dog isn't bothered; she's living her life as well.
During this time, I still haven't been able to touch her even slightly. She keeps hissing and running away from us, hiding under my bed all day, only to come out in the evening. She mostly stays by the door, probably wanting to get out of here.
I live in a small flat with only one room. When I clean, it makes noise so it scares her even more.
It breaks my heart to see her being so scared of me. I've had so many cats in my life, mostly rescues, and it never happened before, so I'm at a loss.
I really don't know what to do to help her trust me, and I'm really worried she'll not change and I'll have a scared cat for the next 12-15 years.
What can I do? Being patient is fine, but she's sneezing as well at the moment and I'd like to take her to the vet for a check-up but how can I do that when she runs away and hides whenever I move?

Do you know anything about the history of this cat? Was she born in human care or as a feral street or barn cat? If she didn't have any positive interactions with humans very early in her life, it may be a very long process until she trusts you. For starters, never look her directly in the eyes, but deliberately do the "lazy cat blink" at her. That's your way of telling her "I'm your friend".

This question is similar to: New Kitten is scared/wary of me when approaching her directly. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Time and patience and possibly treats. It took a month before my most recent two stopped hiding under the guest room bed, and that's without a dog in the house. Comfort with visibility, contact, willingness to relax around me, comfortable distance all progressively improved over following weeks as they decided I was harmless, then interesting, then a heat source, and finally part of the family. Some cats never make it all the way to lap cat; some are never comfortable being picked up. If they didn't have individual, quirky personalities, they wouldn't be cats.

Yes definitely time and lots and lots of patience. Cats are very independent as well as sensitive animals. Their communication is strongly built on talking with their eyes and using body language. Cats don't normally vocalize with each other they vocalize with us humans as their way of trying to communicate with us since we are vocal creatures. With a scared cat I found giving them distance and allowing them to make the decision of when and how they will interact with you for the first time. Cats are also extremely cautious and therefore do not trust easily. Another secret weapon i use all the time and works like a charm for most Cats even the feral and unsociable ones......look at you cat directly in the eyes and very slowly blink and make a tiny tiny squeeze with your eye lids and slowly reopen your eyes. Do that a few times, you will see almost immediately the cat will respond the exact same way. They are basically telling you they don't want to fight that they wish to keep the peace and that they are no harm or a threat to you. When you copy the same eye movements you are relating to the cat the exact same thing that you want peace and mean no harm. Cats will use this method of eye movements to tell their humans in their own little ways that they love you. Other than communicating with a scared cat in this specific way do not try to approach the cat nor try reaching for the cat. The cat will come around and eventually want affection and attention. Especially when they catch on that you are the food provider. Cats also think when us humans leave the house that we are going hunting for them. I try to make sure I have a little treat for my fur babies if I an out of the house and return some time later. It makes my babies beyond happy. I really do wish you luck i don't think you will need it to be honest as it sounds like you are already reading this cat and respecting her space. In no time she will be the very opposite and you won't believe that at one point this is the way she came to you. Plus cats are sensitive about being moved from one place to another and I find it does take them more time to adjust to their new surroundings, with new smells and new noises to adjust to. During the night I am sure she is out and about exploring, as this is the time she knows you are not moving about. And the darkness of night probably comforts her for the mean time.  :))
